# Integration of quotient of tensorial products of unit vectors on the unit sphere

Tags: integration, tensors, spherical-coordinates

It's well known how to perform integrals of the type
([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409144/integrating-unit-vectors-on-the-surface-of-the-unit-sphere))

$$I=\int n_in_jn_k\, d\Omega$$

where $n_i$ are the components of a 3D unit vector and $d\Omega$ is the solid angle. I have encountered integrals of the this type (the one I found actually has 8 on the numerator and 10 in the denoinator)

$$I=\int \frac{n_i n_j}{n_k n_l n_m n_o } d\Omega$$

and I wonder if there exist a general solution as in the first case. Clearly, we get a lot of cancelations when we have odd powers, but I feel it can get very messy without some general approach.

Comment: You might as well as about $\int_{S^2} n_1^a\,n_2^b\,n_3^c\,{\rm d}\Omega$ in general. Does this integral ever even converge if there are negative powers and no odd powers?